# Trackpad Navigation: Invert Pan Direction

Tags: shortcut, navigation

Is it possible to invert or reverse the orientation of panning with a laptop that is using blender numpad emulation? Currently, I use the shift key and two fingers to pan left and right: Sliding to the left moves the scene to the right, and vice-versa. I would like to invert that orientation, so that sliding to the left moves the scene to the left, and sliding to the right moves the scene to the right.

I have searched "Input" and "Navigation" in the preferences, and hunted through "Keymap" to find something that might apply, but with no luck.

Using macOS 13.4.1 here, with Blender 3.6.

Comment: I would also love this feature, it's so weird having godot be reversed from blender